# statsmodles AR model error when calling params

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, statsmodels

New to statsmodels, trying to use statsmodels.tsa.ar_model to fit a pandas timeseries.

```
#pull one series from dataframe
y=data.sentiment
armodel=sm.tsa.ar_model.AR(y, freq='D').fit()
armodel.params()
```

gets the following error:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\lib.pyd in pandas.lib.SeriesIndex.__set__ (pandas\lib.c:27817)()
AssertionError: Index length did not match values
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add some sample data?  When you pass a pandas DataFrame or Series to `AR`, statsmodels [assumes](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR.html#statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR) it has a DatetimeIndex, which has a frequency attached.  So try it without passing the freq argument.  Also check for any `nan`'s.  If you have some try `y = data.sentiment.dropna()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upgrade to current master, if you can. This was fixed [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/722).

Comment: is this in a newer release, or do you suggest just pulling from github?

Comment: It's not released yet. For now it's probably best to use github until we're on a better release cycle. That said, we are finishing up a few outstanding issues and getting a release out ASAP.