# Python statsmodels trouble getting fitted model parameters

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm using an AR model to fit my data and I think that I have done that successfully, but now I want to actually see what the fitted model parameters are and I am running into some trouble.  Here is my code

```
model=ar.AR(df['price'],freq='M')
ar_res=model.fit(maxlags=50,ic='bic')
```

which runs without any error.  However when I try to print the model parameters with the following code

```
print ar_res.params
```

I get the error

```
AssertionError: Index length did not match values
```

Comment: Duplicate, maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128116/statsmodles-ar-model-error-when-calling-params

Comment: I don't know, that post was from months ago, I would think it would be fixed by now...

Comment: Are you using the version with the fix?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check which version I am using, but I'm using ubuntu and I just installed it today so I would think it is the most recent.  I do not know how to update it either

Comment: OK I managed to install from master here https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels but the error persists

Comment: Please consider filing a bug report with a fully reproducible example of the failing code. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce this with current master.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from pandas.util import testing
df = testing.makeTimeDataFrame()
mod = sm.tsa.AR(df['A'])
res = mod.fit(maxlags=10, ic='bic')
res.params
```